# System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync method when webpage contains ™ or other special characters

Tags: asp.net

I am using the System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync async method to upload a web page content and process it or just save it on my local folder. Everything is fine but when the web page contains some special characters like ™ or ®, they are not getting downloaded. Am I missing something here?

```
        String contentToScrapeURL = "https://www.naylornetwork.com/aaho-advertorial/newsletter.asp?issueID=89542";
        Boolean success = true;
        using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            String pageSourceCode = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(contentToScrapeURL);
            String path = @"C:\MyProjects\TestingThings\App_Data\" + "test.html";
            File.WriteAllText(path, pageSourceCode);
        }
```

Comment: I added wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; before doing the async call.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, or remembered it.
I did set the System.Net.WebClient.Encoding to Encoding.UTF8
So this below is the updated code

```
            using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                String pageSourceCode = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(contentToScrapeURL);
                String path = @"C:\MyProjects\TestingThings\App_Data\" + "test.html";
                File.WriteAllText(path, pageSourceCode);
            }
```